# php Remap array keys for multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a JSON object I've turned into an array, this needs to be stored into my database, the trouble is my table has field called `id`, however in the array it's called group_id.

What's the most efficient way of traversing my multi-dimensional array converting all the group_id keys to id so I can pass it to my SQL storage function?  I want to function to work with an array or an array or arrays.

I had planned to make a function:
`$db->remap($array, [ 'group_id' => 'id' ];` then I can pass a list of all the fields I want remapping.

array_walk_recursive doesn't help because it won't let you modify the keys, I looked at a recursive function call, but struggled to keep track of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, including here to help others, if there is a better way please let me know, thanks.

```
 /**
 * Recursively remap array keys
 * @param array $array Array to search
 * @param array $mapping Key value pairs of the keys to map [ 'fromKey' => 'toKey' ]
 * @return array Returned remapped array
 */
public function remapArray(array $array, array $mapping) {
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            // This is also an array, resursively call
            $newArray[$key] = $this->remapArray($value, $mapping);
        } else {
            if (! empty($mapping[$key])) {
                // Match, replace key
                $newArray[$mapping[$key]] = $value;
            } elseif (! in_array($key, $mapping)) {
                // Only store if this key doesn't match the target
                $newArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need recursion? We don't know because you did not provide a [mcve].